# Using presentations, prove $\frac{\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}}{\langle(3,3)\rangle}\cong\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z_3}$.

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, group-presentation, direct-product, combinatorial-group-theory

### The Details:

In considering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1782494/104041) on the same isomorphism and trying to come up with an alternative proof of my own (than the one composed of the work in the question and @DerekHolt's comment), I got stuck.

I want to use the following presentation of $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$,

$$\langle a,b\mid ab=ba \rangle,\tag{$\mathcal{P}$}$$

by killing some element of the presentation.

My guess is to let $c=ab$ then kill $c^3$ in $(\mathcal{P})$, since, say, $(1,0)\mapsto a$ & $(0,1)\mapsto b$ and $a$ & $b$ commute, some other pithy Tietze transformations might elicit an isomorphism of the quotient of $(\mathcal{P})$ by $\langle (3,3)\rangle$ with

$$\langle x,y\mid y^3, xy=yx\rangle,\tag{$\mathcal{Q}$}$$

a presentation of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z_3.$

### The Question:

> Using presentations, prove $\frac{\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}}{\langle(3,3)\rangle}\cong\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z_3}$.

### Thoughts:

*I really think I ought to be able to do this myself*. I work with presentations an awful lot. However, it has taken me the better part of an hour to articulate my hunch.

Please help :)

Comment: What about sending $\overline{(1,0)} \to x$ (rather $\overline{a} \to x$) $\overline{(1,1)} \to y$ (or rather $\overline{ab} \to y$)? You just need to show this is an isomorphism from your quotient group to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}$.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, @MorganRodgers, but what do you mean by, say, $\overline{a}$? It reminds me of tranversals *à la* Magnus *et al.*, but I doubt that's what you mean.

Comment: I've corrected the notation to be clearer, @MorganRodgers; I still don't know what you mean by $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{ab}$. The overline is used differently in Magnus *et al.*'s book *"Combinatorial Group Theory: [. . .]"*.

Comment: I mean if $g$ is in the group, $\overline{g}$ is the corresponding element in the quotient group (ie the coset $g + \langle (3,3)\rangle$)

Comment: No, $(\mathcal{P})$ and $(\mathcal{Q})$ are presentations. I'm using the `tag{$\mathcal{X}$)` code for each, @MorganRodgers. It's a standard tool here.

Comment: No worries,  @MorganRodgers. Thank you for confirming my hunch. Would you care to promote your comment to an answer? I'll accept it, so it'll take this question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a new generator, $c=ab$, and then $b$ is redundant (since $b = a^{-1}c$). Then the subgroup we are quotienting by is just $\langle c^{3} \rangle$, so the quotient group becomes $\langle a,c \mid c^{3},\ ac = ca \rangle$ which is clearly isomorphic to the presentation $(\mathcal{Q})$.

In terms of the presentation (using Tietze transformations), we have
$$\begin{align}
(\mathcal{P}) &\to \langle a,b,c \mid ab=ba, c=ab\rangle \\
&\to \langle a,c \mid c=a^{-1} c a, c=c\rangle \\
&\to \langle a,c \mid  ac=ca\rangle.
\end{align}$$